# POS not getting any response from "api.cardsapp.com"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Using Cards SDK, everything worked great until last night when suddenly I started getting warnings

> Please update API host name

I'm using the correct `api.cardsapp.com` domain without any proxy.

Note all methods are indeed working fine! but I'm worried they'll break sometime in the future.

Comment: What is `POS`? Do you mean a HTTP POST request?

Comment: check with cardsapp,com to see what is going on

Comment: POS = Point of Sale. Thanks guys I found the issue, host name was changed.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently they announced a new hostname, "api.cards.app" and that's why I got "obsolete" warnings.

So note that "api.cardsapp.com" is now "api.cards.app".

I missed the statement here: https://cards.app/Developers/CardReader/Requirements

It says:

> Cards Reader SDK talks to  Cards NFC Gateway API over the internet to verify, identify and authenticate smartphone wallet owners in a highly secure manner. We will access "api.cards.app" on port 443. This will require DNS resolving and frequent HTTP(S) communication, roughly a 15 KB transmition for a single verification process.